# Comparing data tables from same access database in visual studio c# windows form app

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, datatable

I have 2 data table in the same access database, I need to use a specific column in both datatble to compare and output the non-matching datas. I have used

```
private void compare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // Something to do with the Initialization of the FirstDataTable and SecondDataTable   
        connection.Open();
            DataTable dt;

        dt = getDifferentRecords(FirstDataTable, SecondDataTable);

            if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Equal");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Not Equal");
        }




    public DataTable getDifferentRecords(DataTable FirstDataTable, DataTable SecondDataTable)
        {
        //Create Empty Table   
        DataTable ResultDataTable = new DataTable("ResultDataTable");

            //use a Dataset to make use of a DataRelation object   
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {

            //Add tables   
            ds.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[] { FirstDataTable.Copy(), SecondDataTable.Copy() });

                //Get Columns for DataRelation   
                DataColumn[] firstColumns = new DataColumn[ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < firstColumns.Length; i++)
                {
                    firstColumns[i] = ds.Tables[0].Columns[i];
                }

                DataColumn[] secondColumns = new DataColumn[ds.Tables[1].Columns.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < secondColumns.Length; i++)
                {
                    secondColumns[i] = ds.Tables[1].Columns[i];
                }

                //Create DataRelation   
                DataRelation r1 = new DataRelation(string.Empty, firstColumns, secondColumns, false);
                ds.Relations.Add(r1);

                DataRelation r2 = new DataRelation(string.Empty, secondColumns, firstColumns, false);
                ds.Relations.Add(r2);

                //Create columns for return table   
                for (int i = 0; i < FirstDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    ResultDataTable.Columns.Add(FirstDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName, FirstDataTable.Columns[i].DataType);
                }

                //If FirstDataTable Row not in SecondDataTable, Add to ResultDataTable.   
                ResultDataTable.BeginLoadData();
                foreach (DataRow parentrow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    DataRow[] childrows = parentrow.GetChildRows(r1);
                    if (childrows == null || childrows.Length == 0)
                        ResultDataTable.LoadDataRow(parentrow.ItemArray, true);
                }

                //If SecondDataTable Row not in FirstDataTable, Add to ResultDataTable.   
                foreach (DataRow parentrow in ds.Tables[1].Rows)
                {
                    DataRow[] childrows = parentrow.GetChildRows(r2);
                    if (childrows == null || childrows.Length == 0)
                        ResultDataTable.LoadDataRow(parentrow.ItemArray, true);
                }
                ResultDataTable.EndLoadData();
            }

            return ResultDataTable;
        }
```

However when i run this code it tells me Firstdatatable and seconddatatable does not exist in current context so i added

```
public DataTable FirstDataTable;
    public DataTable SecondDataTable;
```

and when i run it again i got this error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'FirstDataTable was null. How do i solve this or is there any other way to do this.

Thank You.
source code i used

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace tryout
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();//setting connection
        public DataTable FirstDataTable;
        public DataTable SecondDataTable;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ndarren\Desktop\Data.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";//change this when using different database!

        }


            private void compare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            // Something to do with the Initialization of the FirstDataTable and SecondDataTable   
            connection.Open();
                DataTable dt;

            dt = getDifferentRecords(FirstDataTable, SecondDataTable);

                if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
                    MessageBox.Show("Equal");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Not Equal");
            }




        public DataTable getDifferentRecords(DataTable FirstDataTable, DataTable SecondDataTable)
            {
            //Create Empty Table   
            DataTable ResultDataTable = new DataTable("ResultDataTable");

                //use a Dataset to make use of a DataRelation object   
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {

                //Add tables   
                ds.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[] { FirstDataTable.Copy(), SecondDataTable.Copy() });

                    //Get Columns for DataRelation   
                    DataColumn[] firstColumns = new DataColumn[ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < firstColumns.Length; i++)
                    {
                        firstColumns[i] = ds.Tables[0].Columns[i];
                    }

                    DataColumn[] secondColumns = new DataColumn[ds.Tables[1].Columns.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < secondColumns.Length; i++)
                    {
                        secondColumns[i] = ds.Tables[1].Columns[i];
                    }

                    //Create DataRelation   
                    DataRelation r1 = new DataRelation(string.Empty, firstColumns, secondColumns, false);
                    ds.Relations.Add(r1);

                    DataRelation r2 = new DataRelation(string.Empty, secondColumns, firstColumns, false);
                    ds.Relations.Add(r2);

                    //Create columns for return table   
                    for (int i = 0; i < FirstDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        ResultDataTable.Columns.Add(FirstDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName, FirstDataTable.Columns[i].DataType);
                    }

                    //If FirstDataTable Row not in SecondDataTable, Add to ResultDataTable.   
                    ResultDataTable.BeginLoadData();
                    foreach (DataRow parentrow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        DataRow[] childrows = parentrow.GetChildRows(r1);
                        if (childrows == null || childrows.Length == 0)
                            ResultDataTable.LoadDataRow(parentrow.ItemArray, true);
                    }

                    //If SecondDataTable Row not in FirstDataTable, Add to ResultDataTable.   
                    foreach (DataRow parentrow in ds.Tables[1].Rows)
                    {
                        DataRow[] childrows = parentrow.GetChildRows(r2);
                        if (childrows == null || childrows.Length == 0)
                            ResultDataTable.LoadDataRow(parentrow.ItemArray, true);
                    }
                    ResultDataTable.EndLoadData();
                }

                return ResultDataTable;
            }




        //core
        private void btn_loadcore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                string query = "select * from core";
                command.CommandText = query;
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt2);
                dataGridView3.DataSource = dt2;
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
            }
        }
        //care
        private void btn_loadcare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                string query = "select * from care";
                command.CommandText = query;
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt4);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt4;
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
            }
        }

        private void prevform_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form1 frm1 =new Form1();
            frm1.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void nextform_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
            frm3.ShowDialog();
        }

    }

}
```

'

[Result i would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjxEP.png)

Comment: Seems like a simple query - _à la_ "table1.Id Not in table2.id" - would do it.

Comment: @Gustav can you show how to do it thank you. Sorry if it is a simple i am still learning c#.

Comment: The query is SQL, not C#.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in c#?

Comment: Loop table one and list records having no match in table two.

Comment: How do I set for example firstdatatable to link to my database table?

Comment: Oh, many ways are offered. Browse for a guide or tutorial and study to find the method that will fit you.